# How can I edit elasticsearch.yml when deploying the StatefulSet via a yml manifest?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, azure-aks

I want to enable the security features of ElasticSearch and according to [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/security-minimal-setup.html) tutorial I need to add `xpack.security.enabled: true` to elasticsearch.yml to do so.

I tried doing this by adding the following command:

```
 command:
   - "sh"
   - "-c"
   - "echo 'xpack.security.enabled: true >> /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml"
```

But this put the pod into a CrashLoopBackOff. At first I thought this was because the elasticsearch.yml file did not exist at this point, but when I changed the command to:

```
 command:
   - "sh"
   - "-c"
   - "cat /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml"
```

I could see with `kubectl logs <pod-name>` that it does exist and contains the following lines:

```
cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Strangely, even if I use a very simple command like `ls` I always get the CrashLoopBackOff.

This is the complete manifest file of the ElasticSearch StatefulSet:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: es-cluster
  namespace: efk-stack
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.10
        command:
            - "sh"
            - "-c"
            - "cat /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml"
        resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: rest
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: inter-node
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        env:
          - name: cluster.name
            value: k8s-logs
          - name: node.name
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: discovery.seed_hosts
            value: "es-cluster-0.elasticsearch,es-cluster-1.elasticsearch,es-cluster-2.elasticsearch"
          - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
            value: "es-cluster-0,es-cluster-1,es-cluster-2"
          - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
            value: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      initContainers:
      - name: fix-permissions
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - name: increase-vm-max-map
        image: busybox
        command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      - name: increase-fd-ulimit
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 3Gi
```

Comment: A container only does one thing; if you override `command:` that is the only thing the container will do.  Can you provide this setting in an environment variable instead, or provide the `elasticsearch.yml` file in a ConfigMap?  Are you writing any code, or just trying to deploy Elasticsearch with specific settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you main goal is simply to edit the `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml` file and then have elastisearch start up as normal?

I that case a ConfigMap and a VolumeMount are your friend.

TL;DR: Create a ConfigMap with the *entire* contents that you want in `elasticsearch.yml` (i.e. not just the part you want to add) and mount that as a volume at `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml`. This will overwrite the file at startup.

As follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
  namespace: efk-stack
data:
  elasticsearch.yml: |-
    foo: bar
    baz: foo
    xpack.security.enabled: true    
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: es-cluster
  namespace: efk-stack
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:

      ### added:
      volumes:
        - name: my-configmap
          configMap:
            name: my-configmap
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.10

        ## removed so that default startup command is used
        # command:
        #     - "sh"
        #     - "-c"
        #    - "cat /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml"

        resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: rest
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: inter-node
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data

        ## added
        - name: my-configmap
          subPath: elasticsearch.yml 
          readOnly: true
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
          
        env:
          - name: cluster.name
            value: k8s-logs
          - name: node.name
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: discovery.seed_hosts
            value: "es-cluster-0.elasticsearch,es-cluster-1.elasticsearch,es-cluster-2.elasticsearch"
          - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
            value: "es-cluster-0,es-cluster-1,es-cluster-2"
          - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
            value: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      initContainers:
      - name: fix-permissions
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - name: increase-vm-max-map
        image: busybox
        command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      - name: increase-fd-ulimit
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 3Gi
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the basic start of the image don't try to use a special exec cmd .
Once your pod did a normal start , use cat file_location_on_pod>>file_location_on_host with kubectl exec to have the file you need to modify on your Host.

Then finally you will just edit it and use it as a mount volume for your pod.

Comment: I saw this concept in a few places: 'create your pod, then edit it with kubectl exec'. But that does not seem scalable? What happens when a pod crashed and starts up again? Do you manually need to keep editing every time?

Comment: For example in [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-basic-setup.html) ElasticSearch tutorial, they say to create a TLS certificate on every pod (they seem to call the pods nodes).